# Use global-messages.properties with Struts2 label tag

Tags: html, struts2, label, ognl, struts-tags

Normally I use an HTML label to label my fields as follows

```xml
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <label class="pull-right">
        <s:text name="fax"></s:text>:
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
    <s:property value="organizationInfo.fax"/>
</div>
```

where `fax` is defined in the `global-messages.properties` file.  But I need to use the `Struts2` `<s:label>` inside of an `<s:iterator>` so each label will have an unique id to connect to each field.  I tried several ways including the following

```xml
<s:iterator value="chosenShipperViewList" status="status">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 ">
        <s:label for="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" class="pull-right">
            <s:text name="deleteShipperInfo"></s:text>:
        </s:label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
        <s:url var="deleteLink" action="shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList">
        <s:param name="shipperName" value="%{organizationInfo.orgName}"></s:param>
            <s:param name="typeOfShipmentId" value="typeOfShipmentId"></s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:a id="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" href="%{deleteLink}"> 
            <img src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" >
        </s:a>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

I could never get `Struts` to generate the `HTML` `label` using the label value from the `global-messages.properties` file.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a standard HTML tag:

```xml
<label for='<s:property value="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" />' class="pull-right">
    <s:text name="deleteShipperInfo"></s:text>:
</label>
```

Or drop `<s:text>` and use `key`:

```xml
<s:label key="deleteShipperInfo" for="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" class="pull-right" />
```